# Collection not modified,Enumeration operation may not execute- in mschart

Tags: c#, real-time, mschart, fiddlercore

I am using Fiddler API. In this API I am using AfterSessionComplete event. This event fires whenever I am accessing any page on the browser. This event also calls the method i.e. (`drawGraph_2(List<Fiddler.Session>)`). The method has the functionality of drawing the graph. I am sharing the code with you. For few requests I am able to draw the graph but once I access too many pages I get this error i.e collection is modified.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Fiddler;
    using System.Threading;

namespace MSRealTime
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static int i = 0;
    List<Fiddler.Session> fs = new List<Session>();
    int iSecureEndpointPort = 8877, get = 0, post = 0, threshold_value = 0;
    string sSecureEndpointHostname = "localhost";
    Proxy oSecureEndpoint;
    static int k = 0;
    TimeSpan cbr, sbr, cdr;
    double rt, request_response_time;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Fiddler.Session> numb = new List<Session>();
        //List<Fiddler.Session> removeprev = new List<Fiddler.Session>();
        #region AttachEventListeners
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate (Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
            oS.bBufferResponse = false;
            Monitor.Enter(numb);
            numb.Add(oS);
            Monitor.Exit(numb);
            oS["X-AutoAuth"] = "(default)";
        };
        //this event fires when server response received by fiddler
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeResponse += delegate (Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
            string s = oS.PathAndQuery;
            int i = oS.port;
        };
        //this event fires when a session has been completed
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += delegate (Fiddler.Session oS)
        {
            //URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess("127.0.0.1:8888", "<-loopback>");
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            if (oS.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT")) { return; }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = numb.Count.ToString();
            }

            //Monitor.Enter(numb);
            numb.Add(oS);
            //removeprev.Add(oS);
            numb = numb.OrderBy(x => x.id).ToList();
            // Monitor.Exit(numb);
            //numb.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(oS.Timers.ClientBeginRequest.ToString()).TotalMilliseconds-TimeSpan.Parse(oS.Timers.ClientBeginRequest.ToString()).TotalMilliseconds);
            drawGraph_2(numb);
            //numb.Clear();
        };
        #endregion AttachEventListeners
        //Fiddler.CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = true;
        FiddlerCoreStartupFlags oFCSF = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;
        try
        {
            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(iSecureEndpointPort, oFCSF);
        }
        catch (Exception exe) { MessageBox.Show(exe.Message); }
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Created endpoint listening on port {0}", iSecureEndpointPort);
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Starting with settings: [{0}]", oFCSF);
        FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Gateway: {0}", CONFIG.UpstreamGateway.ToString());
        oSecureEndpoint = FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint(iSecureEndpointPort, true, sSecureEndpointHostname);

    }
    private void drawGraph_2(List<Fiddler.Session> numb)
    {
        //for (; i < numb.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    fs[i] = numb[i];
        //}
        fs = numb;
        //foreach (Session fs in numb)
        for(;i<fs.Count;i++)
        {
            cbr = fs[i].Timers.ClientBeginRequest.TimeOfDay;
            sbr = fs[i].Timers.ServerBeginResponse.TimeOfDay;
            cdr = fs[i].Timers.ClientDoneResponse.TimeOfDay;
            double cbr_millisecond = TimeSpan.Parse(cbr.ToString()).TotalMilliseconds;
            double sbr_millisecond = TimeSpan.Parse(sbr.ToString()).TotalMilliseconds;
            double cdr_millisecond = TimeSpan.Parse(cdr.ToString()).TotalMilliseconds;
            rt = (cdr_millisecond - cbr_millisecond);                                                                           // page response time
            request_response_time = (sbr_millisecond - cbr_millisecond);                                                          // request response time
            // Add point.
            chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(fs[i].id, rt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before using "numb" list, you have to cast it to list.
fs.ToList();
fs = numb.ToList();

Comment: i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your event `AfterSessionComplete`fires faster than your handler code can process it. So your collection gets modified while you are still iterating it.

You will need to make a copy to have a collection that does not get modified.

You could do this by calling `ToList` on it as suggested:

```
fs = numb.ToList();
```

As you seem to handle it like an array afterwards anyway, you could also create an array straight away:

```
fs = numb.ToArray();
```

Comment: i got the solution. Now i am plotting the graph in mschart with timer tick event. That really remove my bugs.